# How to close ObjectInputStream properly?

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm working with a `FileInputStream` for the first time and try to load objects (`Item`) from a file.

This is my code:

```
    try {

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

        while (true) {
            Item i = (Item)reader.readObject();
            System.out.println(i.getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

I've read that this is the standard way to do it and the code works fine. However, this way the `fi` and `reader` are never closed, since the compiler jumps to the `catch` block as soon as an `EOFException` is thrown.

The compiler doesn't let me close the `fi` and `reader` in the `catch` or a `finally` block. Is this really how it's supposed to be? How do I close the input objects properly?

Comment: Declare the variables outside the try/catch and assign them inside. Then you can close them inside the finally block.

Comment: Use try-with-resources https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use try-with-resources statement and that will look like this:

```
try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f); 
    ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fi)) {        

    while (true) {
        Item i = (Item)reader.readObject();
        System.out.println(i.getName());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Here is [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to learn more about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try with resources statement`:

```
try(FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f)){
    try(ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi)){
         // your code
     }
}
```

That way your inputstreams are closed in any case. Regardless of exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to how scoping works, you want to do it like this, where you try and associate a new `try`/`finally` with each `Stream`:

```
try {

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
    try {
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Item i = (Item)reader.readObject();
                System.out.println(i.getName());
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

    } finally {
        fi.close();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

But in recent versions of java (with try-with-resources) you can do it like this, actually:

```
try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f),
     ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fi)) {

    while (true) {
        Item i = (Item)reader.readObject();
        System.out.println(i.getName());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

And the compile will essentially transform it into the first version.